# Is there a better way to control the PYTHONPATH of a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, pythonpath

I have a set of scripts that has to modify os.sys.path on the fly.  The scripts then kick off a subprocess.   Ideally, the subprocess would have the same os.sys.path as the caller.  I want to avoid passing it in as an argument, since that would require a modification to the subprocess script.

I have code that works and meets all of my needs.  I want to know if there is a better way to do this, and if there are any pitfalls to this approach.

The main process

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

#append a dir thats not on the sys path
sys.path.append('C:/pytest2/')

#convert the sys.path into env variable format
pypath = ''
for d in sys.path:
    pypath = pypath + d + ';'

#create a temp copy of the env variables
myenv = os.environ.copy()

#set PYTHONPATH to match this scripts sys.path
myenv['PYTHONPATH'] = pypath

#setup a python command to echo the sys.path
command = 'python C:/pytest/test_subprocess.py'

#launch the subprocess with the custom env
p = subprocess.Popen(command, env=myenv)
```

C:/pytest/test_subprocess.py

```
import sys
print 'sys path'
print sys.path
```

Running the main process results in this console output

[image]

As you can see, C:/pytest2/ is on the os.sys.path for test_subprocess.py

**EDIT**  Changed os.sys to sys

Comment: could you just set it in your systems pythonpath environment variable?

Comment: Do you mean on the fly or permanently on the machine?

Comment: If you know the path at runtime, and you're not running multiple python modules concurrently it might be a lot simpler to just set it permanently on the machine (and then change it back after if you don't want it to stay that way)

Comment: You should be referring to `sys.path`, not `os.sys.path` (import sys). That is the canonical module. Indirect access through another modules import is not a good design practice.

Answer (score -3):

The PYTHONPATH environment variable just appends to the `sys.path`. Python itself (and the `site` module) initialize the module search path from various sources. You only need to add your one directory via the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Even better would be to just install it in the usual site-packages directory with is already searched. Then you won't have to do anything special in the environment.

Comment: I don't see how this helps me add directories to the path on the fly.

Comment: I'm saying it's almost never necessary to do that. In other words, if you think you have to do that then you're doing it wrong. The setuptools package also provides tools to help the development process, such as manipulating the sys.path for you to run from your workspace. There should really be no code at all in your modules that have to touch sys.path. At most you can manipulate `package.__path__`.

Comment: My code has to procedurally call other scripts in other directories.  These scripts (and the directories they are in) might not even be present when the main script starts (it's a daemon).  So am I doing it wrong?  Or is this one of those "almost never" times?

Comment: You could probably use the [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) function if you want to run the new file in the current interpreter. Or just run the file as you are doing. When Python initializes it sets up most of its search path itself. There's no need to duplicate that in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other.  How can the main process ensure that the sub process will launch with the correct search path?  (Other than giving it the search path, which is what I have done)

Comment: How did the initial Python interpreter know its module search path? Python goes though an initialization phase every time you start it. One of the things it does is initialize `sys.path` before your script even runs. It starts with some built-in ones, and adds more based on `.pth` files it finds and the PYTHONPATH env variable (which only appends additional ones).  The directory the script is in is also added automatically. The `sys.path` is not the same as the system PATH variable.

Comment: The initial script is a daemon with a very limited search path.  After it has launched, folders will be created in network drive locations (by humans), in those folders scripts will be created (by humans), the daemon launches those scripts.  The daemon has to provide those scripts with a sys.path that will allow them to access libraries (the scripts themselves won't know where some of the libraries are, only the daemon does).

Comment: Again, you can use the standard path management machinery to provide it, such as creating a `.pth` file in int site-packages subdirectory. It looks like you are spawning a whole new interpreter each time anyway, so that will also do its normal initialization of `sys.path`, including looking for extensions to it in `.pth` files.

Comment: I think you are missing a large part of the purpose of this code.  I don't want to modify my systems env variables.  I don't want to make a .pth file in my site-packages (as that will effect other code that is ran on this machine).  I simply want to launch a sub process, and control what is on ITS path.  None of the methods you have described will let me do this without ALSO modifying the path of OTHER scripts.

Comment: Well, from my perspective the "large part of the purpose" is unknown to me, since it's not stated. So I have to make some assumptions. I *am* questioning the need for your initial request. Also your code sample is not necessary, and is in fact redundant. The PYTHONPATH and sys.path initialization doesn't work the way you apparently think it does. That's my main point here. It's really not the right question to ask. So, please update your question to be more specific about what your needs are, or ask another question.

Comment: This is not the preferred way to setup PYTHONPATH as it causes interferences between multiple processes.