# How to modify the Python path for a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a Python script *child.py* from *parent.py*, but *child.py* imports modules that are not present in the same directory. So *child.py* first sets the path using `sys.path.append()`.

I want to set the path from `parent.py` and then run `child.py` from my script. The reason is the name of the directory where the modules are present keeps changing according to the version updates. I am trying to run `sys.path.append()` from `parent.py` but it is not reflecting in `child.py`.

How do I solve this?

#### parent.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/path/to/directory-v2")
proc = subprocess.popen(["python3", "child.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
```

#### child.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/path/to/directory-v1")
import module1, module2
...
```

Comment: Can't you just simply pass the path as an argument to the subprocess when creating it?

Comment: There is more discussion here (no good answer yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592563/is-there-a-better-way-to-control-the-pythonpath-of-a-subprocess

Comment: /path/to/directory is the directory where modules to be imported in child.py are present. The child.py itself is present in different directory.

Comment: Did anyone come up with a solution to that?